# How to run 2 process parallel in Scala and Spark?

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing

Env: Spark 1.6, Scala

Hi
I need to run to process parallel. First one, for receiving data and second one for transformation and saving in Hive table. I want to repeat first process with a interval of 1 min and second process with interval of 2 min.

```
==========First Process=== executes once per minute=============    
 val DFService = hivecontext.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
      .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://xx.x.x.xx:xxxx;database=myDB")
      .option("dbtable", "(select  Service_ID,ServiceIdentifier from myTable ) tmp")
      .option("user", "userName")
      .option("password", "myPassword")
      .load()
    DFService.registerTempTable("memTBLService")

  DFService.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("hiveTable")


=============Second Process === executes once per 2 minute =========
var DF2 = hivecontext.sql("select * from hiveTable")
var data=DF2.select(DF2("Service_ID")).distinct
data.show()
```

How can I run this two process parallel and with desired interval in Scala?
Thanks
Hossain

Answer (score 0):

Write two separate Spark applications.

Then use cron to execute each app per your desired schedule. Alternatively, you can use [Apache AirFlow](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org) for scheduling your Spark apps.

Refer to the following question for how to use cron with Spark: [How to schedule my Apache Spark application to run everyday at 00.30 AM(night) in IBM Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402153/how-to-schedule-my-apache-spark-application-to-run-everyday-at-00-30-amnight-i)

Comment: Spark context takes more than 50 sec to initiate, then how can I complete whole task within a minute, if I try to schedule by crontab  or oozie?

Comment: How much data are you reading from SQL Server every minute? If it's a small amount of data, then perhaps a regular (not Spark) Java or Scala app would work better.

With regard to startup time for Spark, I'd recommend avoid Spark for this type of task if at all possible. Given the short runtime, I'm going to guess that these are relatively small writes (as reading from SQL Server, transmitting over the network and writing to disk is < 1 minute)

Comment: your suggestion is a good way to deal with this type of problem. However, I have already done with scala coding. I think Scala Future could be a solution for this type of issues. I never tried Future, if you have some examples related to my issue, please post for me.